# Php, return portion of string before "0"

Tags: php, regex

I search PHP method for return portion of string before "0" has no number (**1-9**) after.

Example :

> 604000

I want to PHP script return :

> 604

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3):

Just use **[rtrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)**  as

```
$str="604000";
echo $str = rtrim($str, '0');
```